# Animate RelativeLayout children when position is changed because of height change

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout in my Android application (I'm using this as a splash screen along with the main menu screen.

**Here's the XML**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.izzivizzi.avant2go.ACMainActivity"
android:background="@mipmap/wallpaper"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    ...................

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainMenuButtons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_middle"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    ...................

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**What it's supposed to do**

At first when the Activity is launched, only the RelativeLayout is displayed with weight 1, which means the children are displayed in the middle of the screen (it's a textview along with some images, but I think that's redundant information here).

After a couple of seconds, the LinearLayout's visibility is set to VISIBLE and it has a weight of 2, which means it pushes the top RelativeLayout up.

Now since the main LinearLayout's animateLayoutChanges is set to true, I was expecting that the RelativeLayout's children will animate to their new position (towards the top of the screen) and the new LinearLayout element will slowly appear.

Well, the LinearLayout does slowly appear but the RelativeLayout's children just blink up because the RelativeLayout position doesn't actually change, it just changes it's height.

**The problem**

Now since the RelativeLayout's children are simply blinked up instead of animated, I need to find a way to animate it towards the top while the LinearLayout slowly appears.

I will greatly appreciate a solution to this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of toggling the visibility, why not add the linear layout in code?

You can leave it in the layout file, just get a reference to it: then remove it, after your few seconds runs, and add it back (make sure to use appropriate layout params with weight set).